# use regex to swap dictionary key for value in text in various contexts (python)?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to make a regex substitution program that can find abbreviations in variable contexts and unabbreviate them.  I am been chipping at this for a while but can't seem to get it.
I want to use the keys in a dictionary to as the pattern to search for and replace with the value in a text file.  My latest unsuccessful attempt is below.  Can anybody point me in the right direction or give me a functional example?

```
import re

text = 'ed (ed) started'
text2 = 'rarely kg/mg'

dic = {'kg': 'kilogram', 'mg': 'miligram', 'ED': 'Emergency Department'}

for key in dic:
    textproc = re.sub(r"[\(\b]" + key + r"[\)\b]", dic.get(key), text)

print (key)
print (dic.get(key))
print(textproc)
```

Comment: Inside a character class, `\b` means backspace, not word boundary.

Comment: Why not `textproc = re.sub(r"{}".format(key), dic.get(key), text)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example:

```py
import re

text = 'ed (ed) started ED'
text2 = 'rarely kg/mg'

dict = {'kg': 'kilogram', 'mg': 'miligram', 'ED': 'Emergency Department'}

def expand_abbr(s):
    initial = s
    for key in dict:
        pattern = r'\b{}\b'.format(re.escape(key))
        s = re.sub(pattern, dict[key], s)
    return f'{initial:20} -> {s}'

print(expand_abbr(text))
print(expand_abbr(text2))
```

Output:

```
ed (ed) started ED   -> ed (ed) started Emergency Department
rarely kg/mg         -> rarely kilogram/miligram
```